# Homogeneous elements in a graded ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, graded-rings

Let $R=\bigoplus_{i \ge 0}R^i$ be a graded ring.  An element $x\in R^i$ is said to be homogeneous of degree $i$. My question is about the word "homogeneous" what does it mean here and why we don't just say $x$ is of degree $i$ without the word homogeneous since it seems to add nothing in the description of $x$ because all elements of $R^i$ are homogeneous of degree $i$ !

Comment: I suspect that the terminology comes from polynomial rings, where the homogeneous elements are homogeneous polynomials.

Comment: So you agree that it is just a terminology but without any further mathematical implications, hence with or without the word homogeneous nothing changes.

Comment: It's a convenient terminology. For instance, it is useful to be able to refer to a homogeneous element without specifying which $R^i$ it belongs to.

Comment: But an element in a graded ring can be of degree $i$ without being homogenous. In the case of polynomials, we have that $x^2 + y^2$ is homogenous of degree $2$, while $x^2 + y$ is of degree $2$, but not homogenous. A similar thing can happen in most non-trivial graded rings.

Comment: But how would you say «$x$ is an homogeneous element» without mentioning its degree? We say things like «the ideal is generated by homogeneous elements» all the time: your proposal would end us up having to introduce names for the degrees of the elements, and we did not even mention the elements!

Comment: @Arthur in the polynomials, $R^i=\{a_ix^i\;| a_i\in F\;\}$ so there is no such $x^2+y^2$ that you are mentioning. So indeed all elements in $R^i$ are homogeneous actually by definition.

Comment: @palio But there is such a thing in the ring of polynomials in two variables, where $$R_i = \left\{\sum_{j = 0}^i a_jx^jy^{i-j} \mid a_j \in F\right\}$$ It also works for more than one variable, of course.

Comment: @Arthur ok so your example $x^2+y$ is not an element of $R_2$ and more generally all elements of $R_i$ are homogeneous.

Comment: @palio Yes. Of course, if you limit it to one variable, then you can still say that $x^2$ is homogenous of degree $2$, while $x^2 + x$ in inhomogenous of degree $2$. So, as long as more than one $R_i$ contains more than $0$, there are non-homogenous elements as well as homogenous. Therefore, the existence of the name "homogenous" is in no way superfluous.